# What is the expected behavior of CalDAV recipient acceptance?

Tags: caldav, sabredav

I'm wondering what expected invitee acceptance behavior is of a self hosted CalDAV server.

We have a [Baikal](https://github.com/sabre-io/Baikal) server set up but are having issues with recipients (that are not on the bakail server) accepting calendar invites. The real issue being that that calendar events are not being updated with the acceptance status. Reviewing the ics files/nodes within dav.php shows that the `PARTSTAT` data always show `=NEEDS-ACTION`.

Again, this is only for users/email addresses that are not on the Baikal server.

**Scenario:**

1. user1@domain1.com sets up calendar event in Mac Calendar
2. Invites user2@domain1.com and user1@gmail.com
3. Invites sent out as [IMip](http://sabre.io/dav/scheduling/) - *we have also extended this plugin to use PHPMailer so that emails that are sent have better delivery*
4. Emails received and user2@domain1.com accepts, event is displayed in their calendar and shows they have accepted and that user1@domain1.com is the organizer and accepted, shows user1@gmail.com as not accepted
5. user1@gmail.com also accepts, event is displayed in their Google calendar and shows they have accepted, shows user1@domain1.com is organizer and accepted, user2@domain1.com shows not accepted
6. user1@domain1.com gets IMip email that user2@domain1.com has accepted.
7. Gets a Gmail email that user1@gmail.com has accepted.
8. user1@domain1.com goes to Mac Calendar and status shows as not accepted from user1@gmail.com

Seems kind of similar to [sabre-io/dav#556](https://github.com/sabre-io/dav/issues/556) but its clear the PARTSTAT is not being updated on our end.

So the real question is... is this normal behavior? ie. iCal acceptance not working across multiple domains?

Comment: Have you found a solution or any kind of info regarding this problem by any chance ?